# Mapping numbers to a data frame with non numerical values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with structure like this :

```
C1               C2              C3                C4          C5
Affected User   Affected User   Affected User   Attachment  Affected User
Attachment      Attachment      Attachment      YESIM       Attachment
Description..   NA              Description..   NA          Client ID
Knowledge S..   NA              Knowledge S..   NA          Description..
NA              NA              NA              NA          Knowledge Search
NA              NA              NA              NA          Product Impacted
```

## Note:I have stripped down the original dataframe to fit here and also replaced the column names to be simpler

I have another dataframe which I want to use for mapping,it's structure is :

```
    x
1   Affected User
2   Application Request Variables
3   Attachment
4   Benetrac Incidents
5   Business Critical Date
6   Client ID
7   Comments
8   Configuration Item
9   Contact Info
10  Description / Priority
11  Knowledge Search
12  Product Impacted
13  QEYE
14  Security Incident Variables
15  SVC - Request for
16  YESIM
```

Now I want to map these values to my original data frame so that it should be like

```
 C1              C2              C3                C4          C5
 1               1               1                 3           1
 3               3               3                 16          3
 10              NA              10                NA          6
 11              NA              11                NA          10
 NA              NA              NA                NA          11
 NA              NA              NA                NA          12
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df1, match, df2$x))
```

if you have exact matches.